# eclipse is not redirecting me to next page

Tags: php, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not able to redirect to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786227/not-able-to-redirect-to-next-page)

My php code is as follows:

Home.php

```
<html>
<form name="Form1" action="Welcome.php" method="post">
    Name : <input type="text" name="txtName">
    Phone Number : <input type="text" name="txtPhNo">
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitIt" value="Submit It">     
</form>
</html>
```

Welcome.php

```
<?php
    ob_start(); 
    session_start();    
    if(!($_SESSION['UName']))
    {
        $_SESSION['UName']=$_POST['txtName'];
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php   
    if(isset($_SESSION['UName']))
    {
        echo  $_SESSION['UName'];
    }               
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Output should be..... Page should redirect to Welcome.php.

But its showing only the blank page and the string Welcome.php.

In browser its working without any issue. But in Eclipse its not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"Browser Output" View is not a browser. Output is rendered as like as a browser on the view, but you're not able to use navigation(link,form,...) on it.
Use Internal web browser or External web browser.