# Not able to redirect to next page

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

I am using Win XP os and XAMPP. I was using eclipse as the editor. In Eclipes I was not able to redirect next page so now I have installed Zend Development Environment.

Now also I am getting the same problem.

My Code is

HomePage.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="Form1" id="FormId" action="Welcome.php" method="post">
    name : <input type="text" name="txtName">
    Phone Number : <input type="text" name="txtPnum">
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitIt" value="Submit It">     
</form>
</body>
</html>


And Welcome.php is

<?php
    ob_start(); 
    session_start();    
    if(!($_SESSION['UName']))
    {
        $_SESSION['UName']=$_POST['txtName'];
    }
    if(!($_SESSION['Ph Num']))
    {
        $_SESSION['Ph Num']=$_POST['txtPnum'];
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php   
    if(isset($_SESSION['UName']))
    {
        echo  $_SESSION['UName'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Session not set<br/>";    
        echo "{$_SESSION['UName']}";        
        echo "The session contains <br>";
        print_r($_SESSION);
    }           
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Its working fine (redirecting to next page) in the Browser but its not working in the debug mode. Both in Eclipse and Zend Development Environment.

Instead of show the content of the next page, it showing the page name.(Welcome.php in my example).

Should I need to install any other extra softwares or code itself worng.... Whats the problem. Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance....!

Comment: which part is supposed to make a redirection, i don't see any 
header('Location: redirect.php') or something

Comment: why do you need the ob_start() in here, your can save the content in a variable instead and echo it when needed

Comment: I am submitting the form, So according to the action="Welcome.php" it should redirect to the Welcome.php page.

Comment: You have to configure a debugger.

Comment: The editor you use has absolutely nothing to do with redirection. That's an HTTP thing, accomplished via the "Location" header. You're basically saying that a wrench is responsible for the bank robbery because it tightened a bolt on the getaway car.

Comment: Oh! @ Ibrahim Diallo, Is ob_start(); causing the problem..?

Comment: For instance, when I set up my netbeans environment I had to download and configure xdebug with the IDE in order for debugging to work.

Comment: Look at the bottom of his question guys, he's asking about the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

which part is supposed to make a redirection, i don't see any header('Location: redirect.php') or something

and why do you use ob_start() here .

you didnt release the output buffer add ob_get_clean(); in the end

```
<?php
    ob_start(); 
    session_start();    
    if(!($_SESSION['UName']))
    {
        $_SESSION['UName']=$_POST['txtName'];
    }
    if(!($_SESSION['Ph Num']))
    {
        $_SESSION['Ph Num']=$_POST['txtPnum'];
    }
    ob_end_flush();
?>
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php   
    if(isset($_SESSION['UName']))
    {
        echo  $_SESSION['UName'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Session not set<br/>";    
        echo "{$_SESSION['UName']}";        
        echo "The session contains <br>";
        print_r($_SESSION);
    }           
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this at the end of your code i am pretty sure it is because you are not releasing the output buffer, although i think it should have done it automatically

```
echo ob_get_clean();
```

**Update:**

I am not really sure why you are using the $_SESSION variable here, but is you want to fix the problem, you can use for example $uname instead of $_SESSION['UName'];

```
Welcome.php

<?php // at the beginning of your file, no spaces or newline
    session_start();
    $uName=$_POST['txtPnum'];
    $txtPnum=$_POST['txtPnum'];
    $_SESSION['UName'] = $uName;
    $_SESSION['PhNum'] = $uName;
?>
<html>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo  $_SESSION['UName']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

you get rid of the ob start since you are still debugging your code. and try one step at a time.
Wish you good look.

Comment: Where should I add this code? in the first file Home.php or Welcome .php?

Comment: at the last line of Welcome.php

Comment: I have added the Line  echo ob_get_clean(); But still i am getting the same problem

Comment: what kind of error are you getting? or are you simply getting a blank page? please provide more details

Comment: Ya sure sir.. Actually I am getting the page name in the browser window. Nothing else. Its not showing the content of the page..!